# Counting number of bracelet configurations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, necklace-and-bracelets

Suppose we have $3$ red beads and $3$ green beads. How many different bracelets can we make from this?

> Initially I thought this was a standard circular permutation but I am getting a non integer value for some reason
>
> Number of ways to arrange the beads in a straight line is $\frac{6!}{3!3!}$ however this number is not divisible by 6, which I assumed needed to be the case to turn it circular.

Comment: For some patterns, there aren't $6$ different places to "start" the circle.  For instance, with $RGRGRG$ there are only really two spots to start the circle (it only depends on the color of the first in the line).

Comment: The [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)) happens to handle this case (for both necklaces and bracelets).